# Question regarding Galois descent of sections of a vector bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, descent, galois-descent

Let $\pi: Y\rightarrow X$ be a finite 'etale Galois morphism between two smooth projective varieties with Galois group $G$. Let $\mathcal{E}$ be a vector bundle on $X$. Then $\pi^*\mathcal{E}$ is a $G$-equivariant vector bundle on $Y$.

Let $s\in \Gamma(Y,\pi^*\mathcal{E})$ be a section. Then the section $\sum_{\sigma\in G}\sigma^*s$ is a $G$-invariant section of $\pi^*\mathcal{E}$.

**Question 1**: Is it true that $\sum_{\sigma\in G}\sigma^*s$ 'descends' to $X$, in other words, does there exist a section $t\in \Gamma(X,\mathcal{E})$ such that $\pi^*t = \sum_{\sigma\in G}\sigma^*s$? I believe this should be true, but I can't find a reference, or at least unable to reconcile whether it follows from the theory of Galois descent.

**Question 2**: This seems to suggest that there exists a map $\Gamma(Y, \pi^*\mathcal{E})\rightarrow \Gamma(X,\mathcal{E})$. Is this true?

Please pardon my lack of knowledge in descent theory. Any reference regarding this topic would be really appreciated.

Comment: The answer is yes to both questions. You can deduce a proof from Bosch, Lutkemohmert, Raynaud "Neron Models" chapter 6 sections 1 and 2 (in particular proposition 1 page 130 and Example B page 139).